Why is the ETH value of this transaction zero?
The incoming ERC20 - USDC token transaction looks like it completed properly but I can't access or convert the tokens and the ETH value is zero... Why?
Transaction hash: 0xa8f7273499e1b6115b09f3744ff997ba1df4c9538509f6103c4c453524d44b49

The token being transferred was created by address 0xe13...562 6 days ago on December 9th, 2024, and is named USDC-ERC20.
It isn't the real USDC token from Circle so it doesn't have any real value, meaning you can't convert the tokens into something else like ETH.
The value tab on etherscan shows you how much ETH was sent alongside the transaction, in your case, the transaction was an ERC-20 transfer() function designed to send ERC-20 tokens, not ETH, which is why it shows 0.

You may view the transfer() function code to see that it is incapable of transferring ETH since it is not marked payable as well.
